# Can I copy a text on a webpage and paste it in a text file?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a webpage which dynamically displays a text which I want to copy into a text file using watir-webdriver or any other additional gems. Is it possible?? If yes, how??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How dinamically ? Javascript or periodic reload ? Did you need it for an functional test or you want to scrap some content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about web-scraping try [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you you have HMTL like this:

```
<div id="tehcodez">teh codez</div>
```

This would save text `teh codez` to file `tehcodez.txt` (not tested):

```
text = browser.div(:id => "tehcodez").text
File.open("tehcodez.txt", "w") {|file| file.write(text) }
```

Comment: I will try and let you know...Thanks anyways.. :-)