# How do I copy data from web page and paste it in file for further use with ruby, watir and cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

The first scenario is run as part of the feature file **registration.feature (feature1)** and has the following content:

> ```
> Scenario: User can register as a Free account
>  Given  I am on the home page
>  When   I navigate to the Register page
>  And    set all required fields for "Free" on the page
>  And    check that info about successful registration is shown
>  And    activate account
>  Then   I copy the Free user information in a data file
> ```

Then  I would like to run the following feature under the **upgrade_accounts.feature(feature2)**

> ```
> Feature:    Upgrade accounts
> As an QA Engineer
> I would like to upgrade my accounts to other types
> So I can make sure upgrade functionality is working properly
>
> Scenario: Existing free account is upgraded to premium
> Given  I navigate to the login page
> When   Sign in as free account retrieved from file
> And    I navigate to updgrade accounts 
> And    I select premium account and submit
> Then   Verify premium package is active
> ```

My concerns are about how I implement the connection between these two features using something that applies to step: `Then   I copy the Free user information in a data file` from feature1 and `When   Sign in as free account retrieved from file` on feature2.

So I guess the question is: *What approach(gem) would be best to use in order to copy data from web page into a file and the read it and use it again?*

Thank you!

Comment: Does anything in this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325947/can-i-copy-a-text-on-a-webpage-and-paste-it-in-a-text-file?rq=1) help?

Answer (score 1):

In general, creating dependencies between features files is discouraged.  You want to be able to run features independently with deterministic results, so coupling features through state will likely produce brittle (and breakable) features.  For example, it would be impossible to successfully execute `upgrade_accounts.feature` without executing `registration.feature`.

If you haven't picked up [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book), it's good guide and resource.  It recommends setting up application state through before hooks in `/support/hooks.rb`

Comment: Agree strongly here.  Sometimes you can break this rule, especially with regard to things like say an admin account that may be difficult to create, and is never deleted or altered.  I make the use of some pre-created data, but only for situations where I am not creating or destroying.  It saves time, but use with care  For other things all my data object (like a 'user' object) know how to create themselves in the system, usually via UI or direct DB calls if supported.

Answer (score 1):

Like Orde says, each scenario is unique & independent:

```
Scenario: User can register as a Free account
Given I am on the home page
When I register for a free account
Then I get a message that registration is successful
And my account is active

Scenario: Existing free account is upgraded to premium
Given I have a free account
When I updgrade my account to a premium account
Then my premium package is active
```

Two features, two completely separate tests. If you have one single step that injects a free account into the system *Given I have a free account*, you will not end up with have a failure in upgrading because the step to register the free account failed.

Also, I took the liberty to cut down on the steps to create and verify the account. All the navigation and such are not necessary in the scenario. That is done in the step definition.